# Is the sysctl.conf file always structured as /etc/sysctl.conf?

Tags: linux, sysctl

I need to know if all distributions of Linux have **sysctl.conf** be under **/etc/sysctl.conf**

I was told that Arch Linux does not. Can configurations set under the aforementioned path be overridden by another file in some distros?

Comment: What research did you do? Did you at least read the man page?

Comment: Yes, if I'm asking is because I could not find a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always. RHEL8 has a dummy file quoting the man page of `sysctl.d`.

`man sysctl.d` can read quite a few places.

```
NAME
       sysctl.d - Configure kernel parameters at boot

SYNOPSIS
       /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf

       /run/sysctl.d/*.conf

       /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
```

A run of `sysctl --system` on a RHEL8 from the box evaluates files in this order:

```
sysctl --system
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/10-default-yama-scope.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-libkcapi-optmem_max.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/50-libreswan.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, so I've found that it can be under these paths:
       /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /etc/sysctl.conf

But I cannot confirm which takes precedence over the other.
Do you know if /etc/sysctl.conf would overwrite other files, if present?

Comment: If you run (beware it's not a dry-run command) `sysctl --system` it will load stuff and tell in which order, I've updated the answer with sample run on one of my servers.

Answer (score 0):

From [man sysctl.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html):

```
       /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /etc/sysctl.conf

       The paths where sysctl preload files usually exist.  See also sysctl
       option --system.
```

From [man sysctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html):

```
   --system
          Load settings from all system configuration files. Files are
          read from directories in the following list in given order
          from top to bottom.  Once a file of a given filename is
          loaded, any file of the same name in subsequent directories is
          ignored.
          /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
          /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
          /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
          /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
          /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
          /etc/sysctl.conf
```

On modern systems `sysctl` configuration is loaded on startup with `systemd-sysctl.service`. From [man systemd-sysctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysctl.service.html):

```
   systemd-sysctl.service is an early boot service that configures sysctl(8) kernel parameters by invoking
   /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl.

   When invoked with no arguments, /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl applies all directives from configuration files listed in
   sysctl.d(5).
```

From what I understand the files are loaded from top to bottom, so configurations stored in `/etc/sysctl.conf` might overwrite configurations set earlier.

Pro tip: `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --cat-config`

Any distribution and vendor and package managers and others who have distribute files may store configurations in any of those directories. Packages will store config in `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`. Typically the `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` are left solely for manual administrator work.

Comment: Thank you, I've missed that